# If we define $\mathrm{null}$ as nothing, is it correct to say $\emptyset = \{\mathrm{null}\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathcal{X} = \{x\}$. Can we say $\mathcal{X} = \emptyset$ when $x = \mathrm{null}$? Thanks very much!

PS: $\mathrm{null}$ means nothing.

Comment: $\emptyset \neq \{\emptyset\}$ as the two sets have different cardinality.

Comment: As per comment, we have to take care with "non mathematical" expressions... If "null  means nothing" then $\{ x \}$ is $\{ \}$ because $\emptyset$ is not "nothing": it is a set with no elements.

Comment: Yes, I did understand the difference between $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}$. I am just not sure how to express a non-existing element in an empty set (even though it seems very weird). Sometimes we need to define such a symbol: just as in the question I described; the set $\mathcal{X}$ changes with $x$, but $\mathcal{X}$ can be an empty set, and in that case which symbol we should choose for such $x$?

Comment: What do you mean by $\{\mathrm{null}\}$? Is that meant to be a set with a single element you're calling $\mathrm{null}$, a set of all (potentially many) "null" (as an adjective) elements, or a set that's empty by dint of membership being an unachievable condition? For the last option, you might have intended e.g. $\{y|y\ne y\}$.

Comment: @J.G. Thanks very much for your comments. Let $\mathcal{X} = \{x\colon x = \log a\}$. If $a < 0$, is there a symbol for such an $x$?

Comment: @Ryan It might be better to write $\{x:e^x=a\}$ so the notation doesn't assume $\log a$ exists (which it does over $\Bbb C$). "is there a symbol for such an $x$?" Did you mean a symbol for such an $\mathcal{X}$?

Comment: @J.G. I mean how to use one notation to express such an $x$ (instead of an expression) just as $\mathcal{X} = \emptyset$.

Comment: If you want to say $\log a$ doesn't exist, just say that. If you contend $\log a$ exists (e.g. $\log(-2)=\log2+i\pi$), use $\log a$ as a symbol normally.

Comment: Yes, if we take the continuation into account.

Comment: There is already notation for this, it is $\varnothing$.  It is perfectly correct to write something like $\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x^2 = -14\} = \varnothing$.

Comment: @Randall Thanks very much for your comments. Let $\mathcal{X} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}\colon x = \sqrt{-14}\}$, then $\mathcal{X} = \emptyset$. But how to use a symbol to represent such an $x$? I saw another comment from you, and I also think $\{\uparrow\} = \emptyset$ looks very wired.

Comment: @Randall It depends on how we consider "nothing".

Comment: *There is no such* $x$, so why bother to represent it?

Answer (score 2):

The clear issue is that there is no way in classical mathematics to have an object that can be "nothing". It is not possible to have some $x$ that can "not exist" in some contexts.

This is unlike some programming languages where you can have a variable $x$ that gets instantiated to NULL, and then a list $[x]$ will be the empty list.

This is not a behaviour we allow in mathematics: something must be something, not nothing, so any set $X=\{x\}$ will contain one element (namely $x$) and therefore cannot be empty.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Let $\mathcal{X} = \{x\colon x = \log a\}$. If $a < 0$, is there a symbol for such an $x$?

Comment: No, such an $x$ does not exist and therefore there is no symbol to refer to it. By the way the set $\mathcal{X}$ is also not well-defined when $a<0$, because it uses a term that does not exist (namely $\log a$). On the other hand, the set $\mathcal{X}=\{ x\,|\, x\neq x\}$ exists, and is the empty set. But there is no symbol for an $x$ in this set, because there is no such element. (Which is the heart of my answer: there is no notation for an element that does not exist.)

Comment: Even in Programming languages , (eg Python) `[None]` has 1 Element , `[""]` has 1 Element , `[[]]` has 1 Element , `[[[]]]` has 1 Element , `[[[[]]]]` has 1 Element , while `[]` has no Element !

Comment: How about the symbol $\uparrow$ (which means "undefined")? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In case your question originates in a kind of perplexity regarding the word " nothing", it may be helpful to observe  that modern logic uses quantification to translate this expression into symbolic language, which shows that " nothing " is not a name , and does not denote anything ( such as " nothingness" or " emptyness") .

For example, " there is nothing in box B " reads as

> there is no $x$ such that $x$ is in box B.

Hence, logic helps to avoid the traps of ( ordinary language ) grammar. Though in ordinary language, we could say that "nothing is an element of the empty set",  a sentence deceivingly  ***suggesting that there is an entity  , namely " nothing" , that is the subject of the predicate***  " being an element of the empty set" , logic tells us that our proposition simply means that :

> the open sentence  "$x$ is an element of $\emptyset$ " is false for
> every value of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

- $\mathcal{X} = \{x\}$

Without checking what $x$ is , we can see that the Number of elements in $\mathcal{X}$ is $1$.

In case of Null Set , $\emptyset$ , the Number of Elements is $0$.

Immediately , we can say $\mathcal{X}$ is not $\emptyset$.

In Current Case , $\mathcal{X}$ is a Set having $1$ Element , where that Particular Element is $NULL$.

**Update , in response to Query by OP** :

There may be Cases where we have to write "Something" like the given Example even though the Null Set may be a Possibility.
Then this is a way to get that :

- $\mathcal{X} = \{x : P(x)\}$

When Condition $P(x)$ is satisfied by Certain Elements , we get $\mathcal{X}$ with those Elements. In Case no element satisfies Condition $P(x)$ , we get Null Set.

**Specific Examples** :

- $\mathcal{X} = \{x : x^2=+4\}$ will give $\mathcal{X} = \{+2,-2\}$ in Integers
- $\mathcal{X} = \{x : 4-letter-words\}$ will give $\mathcal{X} = \{NOON,NULL,MOON,....\}$ containing hundreds of English words.
- $\mathcal{X} = \{x : x^2=-4\}$ (In real numbers) will give $\mathcal{X} = \{\}$ or Null Set
- $\mathcal{X} = \{x : x+1=x+2\}$ (In real numbers) will give $\mathcal{X} = \{\}$ or Null Set

In no such Case , we can write $\mathcal{X} = \{x\}$ to indicate Null Set.
That always indicates Some Set with Exactly 1 Element.

**Update , in response to New Query by OP** :

Even when using $\mathcal{X} = \{\uparrow\}$ , it has 1 Element.
$\mathcal{X} = \{\uparrow,\downarrow,\Uparrow,\Downarrow\}$ has 4 Elements.

I think I get what you want. You want a way to put something between the braces yet still say it is the NULL Set.

Using **Current Notation** , there is a way to achieve what you want :
$\mathcal{X} = \{,\} = \{,,\} = \{,,,\} = \{,,,,\}$ has No Elements , though it looks Weird !

Likewise , you can make your **Own Definition** , or rather **Own Notation** , out of the given list , to say that $\mathcal{X} = \{\uparrow\} = \{ \dot{ }\} = \{\cdot\} = \{\Uparrow\} = \{^\circ\}$ indicates the NULL Set. That is your Choice when making your Article.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I am just wondering how to express a non-existing element in an empty set (even though it seems very weird). Sometimes we need to define such a thing: just as in the question I described; the set $\mathcal{X}$ changes with $x$, but $\mathcal{X}$ can be an empty set, and then which symbol we should choose for such $x$?

Comment: I will try to add some way to state that , shortly.

Comment: You can never have an element of the empty set.  What you can say are conditional statements:  "If such an $x\in \emptyset$ existed, then. whatever.  You can also say $\forall x\in \emptyset$,  this doesn't actually say one exists (in modern logic),  it just says whatever property follows would be true if such a thing existed

Comment: Based on your answer, I come up with an example. Let $\mathcal{X} = \{x\colon x = \log a\}$. If $a < 0$, is there a symbol for such an $x$?

Comment: There is no Symbol for such "$x$" because it does not Exist. There are Symbols for such "$\mathcal{X}$" which are $\emptyset$ or $\{\}$ or Null Set , Etc.

Comment: How about the symbol $\uparrow$ (which means "undefined")? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I Updated "My Answer" to address "your New Query" , @Ryan

Comment: It would be poor style to let something like $\{\uparrow\}$ denote the empty set.  Every mathematician I know would assume this is a set with one element called $\uparrow$.

Comment: Absolutely true , I agree with that , @Randall , It will be wholly **Non-Standard** to try that , but OP seems to be very much into **not** using $\emptyset$ or $\{\}$ hence I left that Choice to OP !